# There should be a space between the period and the N

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

https://stackoverflow.com/election/ reads:

> This election is currently in the nomination phase.Nominations close in 7 days

The space after the S of “days” should be moved to just before the N of “nominations.” IMO, there should also be a period following “days.”

Comment: Obviously the most important thing. +1

Comment: Shouldn't there also be a period after `7 days`?

Comment: 7 should be spelled out as seven. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/979/why-do-english-writers-avoid-explicit-numerals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elections are important. As is punctuation.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2014.2.10.1360).